# How to style a button, in query mobile, by ID or Class

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a Submit Button like this:

```
<input type="submit" data-corners="false" id="code_check_button" tabindex="5" data-rel="external" value="GO">
```

which - with a custom css theme - outputs this: http://sht.tl/59y3m

Now I would like to use the id (#code_check_button) to style the button with more specificity.

Unfortunately jquerymobile automagically transforms the input type submit in a snippet of code I cannot control: http://sht.tl/cQq
As you can note, the original button ID is useless...

Can you tell me how may I custom style that button (of course, without wrapping it in an extra tag...)?
Thank you!

Comment: jQM wraps `<button>` with a div. Create a custom class `.custom` and add it to that div. `$("#button_id").closest("div").addClass("custom");`.

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet add the ID `#code_check_button` and provide the desired style you want.. see example below :-

```
#code_check_button {
    your desired style properties here...
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can use the class of the generated div and style the button accordingly. In this generated snippet you have two elements to style. please find below :-

```
.ui-btn {
   style properties here...
}
.ui-btn .ui-btn-text {
   style properties here...
}
```

Comment: Yep, it ain't that easy. If you see the output code,  http://sht.tl/cQq, you'll notice that #code_check_button is hidden and replaced by a jquery dom-generated code... #code_check_button is useless in css...

Comment: Well that could be a way but unfortunately it affects ALL the buttons in the theme... I need to style THAT button differently.

Answer (score 0):

Numerous ways this can be achieved.. 
Here are a few examples:

```
submit {
     styles:styles;
}
```

Not the most compatible in older browsers:

```
input[type="submit"] {
     styles:styles;
}
```

Then you can target the ID:

```
#code_check_button {
     styles:styles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If something keeps changing your intended css into useless code, this may be a situation where you would resort to simple text (eg. nano for mac or notepad for windows) Web design programs are double edged swords, most of the time the bells and whistles on these programs help make things easier, but sometimes they can make things more complicated. To custom style a button all you have to do is put your id or class selector name in the input tag and then enter the css for it. For example

CSS

```
#code_check_button { background-image: url(/*desired image url*/);
                     background-color: /*desired background color*/;
                     color: /*desired font color*/; }
```

HTML

```
<input id="code_check_button" type="submit" name="submit">
```

Just try it in notepad this time.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#code_check_button {
color:#000 !important;
width:200px !important;
}
```

You can see I have added !important tag in all the css properties. This is because of overwritten the jQ mobile default styles.